# My cursor has a part of a duplicate that follows it around

Tags: windows-10

I have my cursor on screen, and a small piece of a copy of the cursor floats under it on screen, about 2 cm away. What would cause this and how do I fix it?

I would add a picture but I can't seem to get one at low enough resolution to upload.

Comment: Wonky video driver.

Comment: Sounds like you turned on mouse pointer trail accidentally.

Comment: And if you start windows in safe mode?